# Issue about different version between history and React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history, react-router-dom

I have no idea what is going on. It's started when i wanna run my react app and i got an error that says :

> You have provided a history object created with history v4.x or v2.x and earlier. This version of React Router is only compatible with v3 history objects. Please change to history v3.x.

I haven't made any changes since my react app works fine.

Here is my App.js code where i use react-router-dom

```
import React from 'react';
import {HashRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import asyncComponent from './AsyncComponent';
import AppShell from './AppShell';
// import authClient from './authClient';
// import Login from './Login';

const Dashboard = asyncComponent(() => {
  return import(/* webpackChunkName: "dashboard" */ './dashboard/Dashboard')
    .then(module => module.default);
});

const Asesmen = asyncComponent(() => {
  return import(/* webpackChunkName: "asesmen" */ './asesmen/Asesmen')
    .then(module => module.default);
});

const AsesmenDetail = asyncComponent(() => {
  return import(/* webpackChunkName: "asesmendetail" */ './asesmen/AsesmenDetail')
    .then(module => module.default);
});

const CreateAsesmen = asyncComponent(() => {
  return import(/* webpackChunkName: "createasesmen" */ './asesmen/CreateAsesmen')
    .then(module => module.default);
});

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <AppShell>
          <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="/asesmen/" component={Asesmen} />
            <Route path="/asesmendetail/" component={AsesmenDetail} />
            <Route path="/createasesmen/" component={CreateAsesmen} />
          </div>
        </AppShell>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am really looking forward solution for this problem.

Thank you

Comment: what's your `react-router` version? Try using v4

Comment: this is my react router version based on package.json

"react-router": "^3.2.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",

Comment: install `react-router` 4.2.0 and try again

Comment: It solved. But now i got new error `Cannot read property 'ReactCurrentOwner' of undefined`.

Comment: okay try this for me. Delete your `node_modules` folder and re-run `npm install`

Comment: I think you might have two versions of `react-router` clashing. Let me know after trying.

Comment: Got it.. i just need to change react version to the correct one. and it's 16. Thank you for your help @forJ